# Change user's boolean when signing out on Flask

Tags: python, flask

Every time a new user is connected to the server I got a list of the users that refresh to show them in my page. I'm using a boolean for that, every time a user is connecting their boolean changes to True and my list is looking for users with the boolean True only. I'm trying now to change the boolean back to False when they sign out. How can I do this?

```
@app.route("/sign-in", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signin():
    
    form = forms.SignInForm()
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            username = form.username.data
            password = form.password.data
    
            # Retrieve the user that matches this username
            user = models.User.query.filter_by(name=username).first()
            print(user.boolean)

            # Check the provided password against the user's one
            if user is not None and user.password == password:
                flask_login.login_user(user)
                flask.flash(f"{user.name} logged in successfully !", "success")
                idn = user.id
                user.boolean = True
                db.session.commit()
                print(user.boolean)
                return flask.render_template('user_page.html', user=user)
            else:
                flask.flash("Something went wrong.", "danger") # Put the message into the flashed messages
                # To retrieve those messages: flask.get_flashed_messages()

    return flask.render_template("signin.html", form=form)

@app.route("/sign-out", methods=["GET"])
def signout():
    flask_login.logout_user()
    return flask.redirect('/sign-in')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the signout route:

```
@app.route("/sign-out", methods=["GET"])
def signout():
    user = models.User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    user.boolean = False
    db.session.commit()

    flask_login.logout_user()
    return flask.redirect('/sign-in')
```

Comment: tried that already it just doesnt know what current_user is in this context

Comment: If `logout_user()` is working `current_user` should also. Try `flask_login.current_user`

Comment: If my answer helped you I'd appreciate it if you accepted it ;)